# Is there a time when 'gets' would be used without 'chomp'?

Tags: ruby, chomp

When collecting user input in Ruby, is there ever a time where using `chomp` on that input would not be the desired behavior? That is, when would simply using `gets` and not `gets.chomp`be appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you specify the maximum length for input, having a "\n" included in the `gets` return value allows you to tell if Ruby gave you `x` characters because it encountered the "\n", or because `x` was the maximum input size:

```
> gets 5
abcdefghij
=> 'abcde'
```

vs:

```
> gets 5
abc\n
=> 'abc\n'
```

If the returned string contains no trailing newline, it means there are still characters in the buffer.

Without the limit on the input, the trailing newline, or any other delimiter, probably doesn't have much use, but it's kept for consistency.